# GWT - RPC serialization exception and MapDB

Tags: java, serialization, gwt, mapdb

I'm using gwt and I'm using mapdb and when I retrieve data as a map (BTreeMap) gwt throw rpc serialization exception. I wrapped the map in an object that implements `Serializable` and `IsSerializable` but that don't work.

I don't know why this doesn't work because I read the documentation of mapdb and I use that correctly.

That's the code:

```
public class WrapperObject implements Serializable, IsSerializable {

          private Map<String, List<String>> map;

          public WrapperObject() {}
          public WrapperObject(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
              this.map = map;
          }
          //GETTERS AND SETTERS
          ...
}


public class Prova {
    ....

    private DB openDB() {
        return DBMaker.shoutdownOnJvmClose().make();
    }

    ...

    public WrapperObject retrieveData() {
        DB db = this.openDB();

        Map<String, List<String>> map = 
        db.getTreeMap("values");

        return new WrapperObject(map);
    }
}
```

Then in the client class I create a Tree with treeItem using the map.

Thank you for help.

Comment: your `WrapperObject` is allocated in the shared package? You tried compiling again?

Comment: it will be great if you put complete exception stacktrace

Comment: are you running your code in development using super dev mode. this may be a cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is, that `Map` is not `Serializable`.

I.e. your `WrapperObject` is marked as `Serializable` and `IsSerializable`,
but not all of its Members  are marked in that way (see `Map` and the wrapped `List`).

To solve this problem you could change the type of `map` to an implementation of `Map` which is serializable (E.g. `LinkedHashMap` with `ArrayList`):

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map;
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I'll try later.